# ruby string literals cached?

Tags: ruby, string

I have code of this form:

```
class String
  def is_jpg?
    start_with? "\xFF\xD8\xFF".b
  end
end
```

String#b returns a copy of a string but encoded as ASCII-8BIT.  My question

Is the ruby interpreter smart enough to cache the result of b() in the example above such that calls to this method for different String instances don't have to create a new copy of "\xFF\xD8\xFF" each time?  Or should I do something like:

```
class String
  JPG_SIGNATURE = "\xFF\xD8\xFF".b
  def is_jpg?
    start_with? JPG_SIGNATURE
  end
end
```

Does the answer depend on the ruby version and/or interpreter?  I'm using MRI 2.2.x soon to be 2.3.x.

Comment: can't you save the result from the `b` method as a constant?

Comment: @davidhu2000 That's what he is doing in last snippet.

Comment: Just an aside, you shouldn't use `is_` prefixes. The method should just be called `jpg?`.

Answer (score 3):

No, by default Ruby will create a new copy of the `String` but you can prevent this by freezing the `String`

```
class String
  def is_jpg?
    start_with? "\xFF\xD8\xFF".freeze.b
  end
end
```

or

```
class String
  JPG_SIGNATURE = "\xFF\xD8\xFF".freeze.b
  def is_jpg?
    start_with? JPG_SIGNATURE
  end
end
```

You can read more about this in this article. http://blog.honeybadger.io/when-to-use-freeze-and-frozen-in-ruby/

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know freeze could be used in this too.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

> Is the ruby interpreter smart enough to cache the result of b()

No. It's against the Ruby core concepts. A string literal like that will be treated as new object everytime.

```
def foo
  x = 'foo'
  puts x.object_id
end

> foo
70281000268840
> foo
70281000264340
```

Your second alternative is the better way to do this. Constant should be defined once. And it will hold single space in memory.

You can also define the same with `String::JPG_SIGNATURE = "\xFF\xD8\xFF".b`

**Edit**: Read the [kcdragon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235908/1376448). He suggested `freeze` to handle it and benchmark number for same are really pretty!

Comment: Certainly if you assign to a variable it cannot cache the result because reusing the object ID would be inconsistent with the language model. But it could be cached in OP's first example without harm. I would guess that this is Ruby-VM-dependent.

Comment: If I assign to a variable (and not a constant), it's scope is limited within that method and on each invocation of method, a new space/new-object will spring in existence, even in first example of OP.

Answer (score 0):

I benchmarked three implementations: normal without optimization, using a const, and using a frozen string.

```
            user     system      total        real
normal  0.270000   0.000000   0.270000 (  0.272052)
const   0.160000   0.000000   0.160000 (  0.155427)
freeze  0.240000   0.000000   0.240000 (  0.238170)
```

It appears that on my machine using the official Ruby VM, the string is not cached because using a const does provide a speed boost. Freezing the string also provides a boost but a substantially smaller one.

Note that I had to call the method *millions* of times in order to see any appreciable difference. I would classify this as premature optimization unless your profiling has showed this specific method to be a serious bottleneck.